# How to load balance among SpringBoot instances

Tags: apache, spring-boot, load-balancing

I have this AngularJS app which uses a backend REST API written in SpringBoot.
I want to run several instances of this backend API on different ports, using SpringBoot.
How can I load balance between those SpringBoot instances?

I tried using Apache, but it does not seem to work:

```
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://54.152.52.248:9999/restApi/v1 loadfactor=5
    BalancerMember http://54.152.52.248:9898/restApi/v1 loadfactor=5
    # Set counting algorithm to more evenly distribute work:
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

<Location /balancer-manager>
    SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
```

The balancer members correspond to two Java processes, different ports.
What I'm trying to do above is to define the context /balance-manager which is gonna be handled by a proxy which in turn is going to distribute requests to those balancer members; if I can prove this happens, I can continue with sticky sessions and of the sort.

The objective is for the angular rest client to request to this single balancer-manager/some_service/some_parameters/ and that this proxy makes the appropiate redirection, which I don't believe is gonna happen with what's above.

Any ideas if this should work?

Thanks.

Comment: What this has to do with AngularJS?

Comment: Have you looked at Hystrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try API Gateway pattern, with Spring Cloud Netflix. Zuul and Ribbon act as proxy and load balancer, distribute requests to different app instances.

[API Gateway Pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)
[Spring Cloud Netflix](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/)